# ATS and http in iOS 10

Tags: ios, ios9, ios10, app-transport-security

In iOS 9 with ATS (App Transport Security) enabled without any exceptions I could not connect to a server via http. Which I would expect.

IE:

http://192.168.22.33

However with no changes in iOS 10 I can make that connection.

Looking here I don't see any updates on why this might be:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS10.html

Any ideas?  I want to make sure I am still getting ATS protection.

Comment: What base SDK was the app build against?  Are you using Xcode 7 or 8 to build the app?

Comment: base SDK is 9.3, building with Xcode 8.  Also important, this same build on 9.3 device won't allow http (as expected), but on iOS 10 it will.

Comment: And how are you making the connection?  In a UIWebView, NSURLConnection? I'll see if I can replicate.

Comment: I am using AFNetworking.  So I guess NSURLConnection under the hood.

Comment: I'm not using AFNetworking, just straight NSURLConnections, and mine behaves the same in iOS 10 as it does in iOS 9.  The only thing I can think that may be the reason (I didn't have a chance to confirm) is that the change is due to the fact that you are using an IP address instead of a domain name to connect to the server.  Maybe iOS 10 allows IP based connections to bypass ATS restrictions?  Or maybe it is because it is a local IP?

Comment: @wottle agreed, it seems for some reason iOS 9 (ATS) did not allow http to an IP address and iOS does.

Comment: I try http://192.168.22.33 failed to connect in iOS 9, but success iOS 10. Both with ENABLE ATS. I don't know what happen.

Answer (score 2):

> Availability of ATS for Remote and Local Connections
>   App Transport Security (ATS) applies only to connections made to public host names. The system does not provide ATS protection to connections made to:
>
> - Internet protocol (IP) addresses
> - Unqualified host names
> - Local hosts employing the .local top-level domain (TLD)
>
> To connect to an unqualified host name or to a .local domain, you must set the value of the NSAllowsLocalNetworking key to YES.
>
> Note: Although ATS is unenforced for connection to local hosts, Apple strongly recommends using Transport Layer Security (TLS) for any local connection, along with the use of a self-signed certificate to validate the local IP address.  [Apple Doc.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33)

The system does not provide ATS protection to connections that with `Internet protocol (IP) addresses`.  So We can connect to server IP without any `NSAllowsLocalNetworking` in the plist file.